# Ability to explicit define "rule element labels"

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Following https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-element-labels is there a way to explicitly add a field to a rule context object?

My use case is a sequence of dots and identifiers:

```
dotIdentifierSequence
    : identifier dotIdentifierSequenceContinuation*
    ;

dotIdentifierSequenceContinuation
    : DOT identifier
    ;
```

Often we want to deal with the "full path" of the `dotIdentifierSequence` structure.  Atm this means using `DotIdentifierSequenceContext#getText`.  However, `DotIdentifierSequenceContext#getText` walks the tree visiting each sub-node collecting the text.

Rule labels as discussed on that doc page would let me do:

```
dotIdentifierSequence
    : i:identifier c+=dotIdentifierSequenceContinuation*
    ;
```

and add fields `i` and `c` to the DotIdentifierSequenceContext.  However to get the full structure's text I'd still have to visit the `i` node and each `c` node.

What would be awesome is to be able to define a "full sequence text" String field for both DotIdentifierSequenceContext and DotIdentifierSequenceContinuationContext.

Is that in any way possible today?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to do this was the following:

```
dotIdentifierSequence
    returns [String fullSequenceText]
    : (i=identifier { $fullSequenceText = _localctx.i.getText(); }) (c=dotIdentifierSequenceContinuation { $fullSequenceText += _localctx.c.fullSequenceText; })*
    ;

dotIdentifierSequenceContinuation
    returns [String fullSequenceText]
    : DOT (i=identifier { $fullSequenceText = "." + _localctx.i.getText(); })
    ;
```

Which works, but unfortunately makes the grammar quite unreadable.